# re.sub not giving expected result in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might be something really simple but why re.sub is not working in below scenario? I want to replace "z4" with "z3"

```
import re

group2="(a1, a2, a3, a4, z1, z2, z3, z4);"
print("group2=",group2)

re.sub('z4','z3',group2)

print("modified gorup2=",group2)
```

Here is the output:

```
group2= (a1, a2, a3, a4, z1, z2, z3, z4);
modified gorup2= (a1, a2, a3, a4, z1, z2, z3, z4);

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `re.sub` doesn't modify `group2` in-place. Use `group2 = re.sub('z4', 'z3', group2)`

Comment: group2 = re.sub('z4','z3',group2) will resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub` will return a new string
    import re

```
group2="(a1, a2, a3, a4, z1, z2, z3, z4);"
print("group2=",group2)

modified_group=re.sub('z4','z3',group2)

print("modified gorup2=",modified_group)
```

Output

```
group2= (a1, a2, a3, a4, z1, z2, z3, z4);
modified gorup2= (a1, a2, a3, a4, z1, z2, z3, z3);
```